# Tooltip Positioning

Tags: css, tooltip, positioning

I am trying to position this tooltip center under a table column but it's not working even if I set position absolute, I do not want to set it as fixed as this tooltip is being used for many other links on the site and same page., it moves as I move the mouse in table test.

can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

CSS Code.

```
#dhtmltooltip{
position: absolute;
min-width:50px;
color:#ffffff;
padding: 6px;
background-color: #2588B3;
visibility: hidden;
z-index: 100;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px; 
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
```

see screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: Can you post a working example on JSFiddle? http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: O.T: If you use the element often and more then once on one page you should also consider changing the ID selector to a class selector.

Answer (score 0):

I found a better tooltop online.

```
.tooltip:hover {text-decoration:none;} 
.tooltip span {
z-index:10;
display:none; 
padding:6px 8px;
margin-top:25px;
width:120px; 
-webkit-border-radius: 8px; 
-moz-border-radius: 8px;
border-radius: 8px;
}

.tooltip:hover span{
display:inline; 
position:absolute;  
color:#EEE;
background:#2588b3;
}

.callout {
z-index:20;
position:absolute;
top:-12px;
left:60px;
}
```

Thanks again fellas. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can position your toolTip center.
By using calc function in css to left attribute in your css.
if you want place in the other position just change the 50% value according your requirements.
Here is the code

```
tooltipCss
{
position: absolute;
left: calc(50% - 5px)
}
```

Thanks.